# Какую выбрать CMS?

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, joomla, cms

Доброго времени суток! У меня такой вопрос. Я хотел узнать ваше мнение насчет выбора `CMS`. Сразу скажу -- в этом деле я новичок. Немного знаком с `Wordpress`'ом. Хотел бы услышать советы какая `CMS` самая удобная для: 1) верстки по шаблону 2) внедрения в `PHP` код своих скриптов 3) по наличию готовых тем (и укажите ресурсы) и т.д. Какие основные различия между `Joomla` и `Wordpress`? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Тут нужно 20 минут погуглить, и все вопросы отпадут. А ответ тут может на неплохую статью потянуть.

Comment: Если напишите такую статью -- плюсану )))

Comment: ахаха... писать статью ради 25+ не...

Гугл разрулит этот ответ :)

Comment: Если погуглите и ответите на свой вопрос сами, тоже не обижу плюсом.

Comment: Может кто-нибудь вставит хорошую статью из гугла?

Comment: Скоро будет. =)

Comment: Вопрос поставлен в корне неверно. Нужно выбирать CMS под вполне определенные задачи. Для клепания г-сайтов подойдет любая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот "ИМХО" обзор](http://blog.niksite.ru/obzory/programmy/cms/7_populyarnykh_cms_nebolshoi_subektivnyi_obzor.html)
[Вот более проф. обзор](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/92607/)
[Вот вообще сайт по CMS](http://cmslist.ru/)

- [Ну и сравнение разных](http://cmslist.ru/find_cms/)

И далее по вышесказанному примеру, мучаем [гугл](http://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=seb&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&site=webhp&source=hp&q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B+CMS&pbx=1&oq=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B+CMS&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=15835l19431l2l20149l10l8l2l0l0l1l124l784l5.3l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c046413aadcd1754&ix=seb&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=963).

Answer (score 0):

Не смотрели PyroCMS ?
Поглядите.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla на мой взгляд CMS ужасно неудобная и в плане интерфейса и в плане создания шаблонов. WP отличная бесплатная блоговая CMS. С шаблонами заморочек быть не должно. Там обычный HTML в перемешку с PHP. Ну а сам я использую платную DLE. Мне она больше, чем WP пригляделась. С шаблонами однозначно все как надо. Все файлы шаблона имеют правильные имена и сразу не сложно понять, за что это файл отвечает. Модули легко подключать и создавать. В общем выбирайте

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress достойная CMS,  тем более вы с ней уже знакомы, так что пользуйтесь ей, по мне в Wordpress проще разобрать чем в чем то другом (ну конечно если не брать в учет ucoz.ru).

Comment: Про ucoz-лятину можно было и не упоминать ))

Comment: Многие на нем начинали, я про юкоз.